# How to search history table with conditions and update in same table?

Tags: sql

I needs a query which can satisfy the below logic.The logic is created by me but I am not that expert to put this in SQL format .

The logic is that we  have to find Y and L in client table and copy the columns. 
Only its N in client then we to have to search for first Y in History and update or if there is no Y in History then we have to look for first L and update

I will be grateful if someone helps me to modify this.

The `client` table has latest data and `client_h` has the history of same client .

```
 If     client.FLAG  = ‘Y’ or ‘L’ , Then 

    UPDATE client SET 
    client.FLAG_new  = client.FLAG, 
    client.DT_new = client.DT  

    ELSE 

    If client.FLAG= ‘N’ then 

    select Min(client_h.DT) from client_h where client_h.FLAG=‘Y’ 
    UPDATE client SET 
    client.FLAG_new  = client_h.FLAG, 
    client.DT_new = client_h.D


    Else 
    select Min(client_h.DT) from client_h where client_h.FLAG=‘L’ 

    UPDATE client SET 
    client.FLAG_new  = client_h.FLAG, 
    client.DT_new = client_h.DT
```

Comment: If you provide table structure and some sample data then it would be more helpful than providing this query. This query is very difficult to understand and it drives to the confusion.

Comment: @Susang Sorry I dont know where to make table but I have made changes in the names of the columns above . This may simplify the logic. Pls help

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql - not the use of the case statement in the set.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLIENT,CLIENT_H;
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (ID INT, FLAG_new VARCHAR(1), FLAG VARCHAR(1),  DT_new  DATE, DT  DATE);
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_H (ID INT, FLAG_new VARCHAR(1), FLAG VARCHAR(1),  DT_new  DATE, DT  DATE); 

TRUNCATE TABLE CLIENT;
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES 
(1,NULL,'Y',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(2,NULL,'L',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(3,NULL,'N',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(4,NULL,'K',NULL,'2018-01-01');

INSERT INTO CLIENT_H VALUES 
(1,NULL,'Y',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(2,NULL,'L',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(3,NULL,'K',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(3,NULL,'Y',NULL,'2018-02-01'),
(4,NULL,'M',NULL,'2018-01-01'),
(4,NULL,'L',NULL,'2018-03-01'),
(4,NULL,'K',NULL,'2018-04-01');

UPDATE CLIENT C
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CLIENT_H H WHERE DT = (SELECT MIN(DT) FROM CLIENT_H H1 WHERE H1.ID = H.ID AND H1.FLAG = 'Y')) HY ON HY.ID = C.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CLIENT_H H WHERE DT = (SELECT MIN(DT) FROM CLIENT_H H1 WHERE H1.ID = H.ID AND H1.FLAG = 'L')) HN ON HN.ID = C.ID
SET 
C.FLAG_NEW = CASE WHEN C.FLAG IN ('Y','L') THEN C.FLAG 
                      WHEN C.FLAG = 'N' AND HY.FLAG = 'Y' THEN HY.FLAG
                        WHEN HN.FLAG = 'L' THEN HN.FLAG
                 END,
C.DT_NEW =   CASE WHEN C.FLAG IN ('Y','L') THEN C.DT 
                      WHEN C.FLAG = 'N' AND HY.FLAG = 'Y' THEN HY.DT
                        WHEN HN.FLAG = 'L' THEN HN.DT
                 END
;

SELECT * FROM CLIENT; 

+------+----------+------+------------+------------+
| ID   | FLAG_new | FLAG | DT_new     | DT         |
+------+----------+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | Y        | Y    | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
|    2 | L        | L    | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
|    3 | Y        | N    | 2018-02-01 | 2018-01-01 |
|    4 | L        | K    | 2018-03-01 | 2018-01-01 |
+------+----------+------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

sql server

```
UPDATE C
SET 
C.FLAG_NEW = CASE WHEN C.FLAG IN ('Y','L') THEN C.FLAG 
                      WHEN C.FLAG = 'N' AND HY.FLAG = 'Y' THEN HY.FLAG
                        WHEN HN.FLAG = 'L' THEN HN.FLAG
                 END,
C.DT_NEW =   CASE WHEN C.FLAG IN ('Y','L') THEN C.DT 
                      WHEN C.FLAG = 'N' AND HY.FLAG = 'Y' THEN HY.DT
                        WHEN HN.FLAG = 'L' THEN HN.DT
                 END
from client c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CLIENT_H H WHERE DT = (SELECT MIN(DT) FROM CLIENT_H H1 WHERE H1.ID = H.ID AND H1.FLAG = 'Y')) HY ON HY.ID = C.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CLIENT_H H WHERE DT = (SELECT MIN(DT) FROM CLIENT_H H1 WHERE H1.ID = H.ID AND H1.FLAG = 'L')) HN ON HN.ID = C.ID
```

Comment: Is it possible to update the DT_NEW without checking the flag once FLAG_NEW gets update. As DT_NEW and FLAG-NEW are of same customer . Pls reply

Answer (score 1):

Below query produces the desired result in postgresql.

**Table "Client"**

```
    | col_name | type      |
    | -------- | --------- |
    | id       | integer   |
    | flag     | text      |
    | dt       | timestamp |
    | flag_new | text      |
    | dt_new   | timestamp |
```

**Table "client_h"**

```
   | col_name  | type      |
   | --------- | --------- |
   | client_id | integer   |
   | flag      | text      |
   | dt        | timestamp |
```

**Query**

```
 with new_client(id,flag,dt) as (
  select
   id,
   coalesce(ch.flag,c.flag),
   coalesce(ch.dt,c.dt)
  from client c
  left join lateral (
   select
    flag,dt
   from client_h
   where client_id=c.id and flag!='N'
   order by flag='Y' desc, flag='L' desc, dt
   limit 1
  ) ch on c.flag='N'
 )
 update client set flag_new = nc.flag , dt_new = nc.dt
 from new_client nc
 where nc.id=client.id
```